# Por qué no funciona mi .then y .catch en fs

Tags: nodejs

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.mkdir('./carpeta_nueva')
  .then(() => console.log("Directorio creado exitosamente"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Mi duda es por qué no funciona el fragmento de código anterior; sé que puedo pasar una función como tercer parámetro pero quiero hacerlo con `then` y `catch`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que quiere decir que no funciona? tira un error?

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando una version reciente de Node, puedes usar `fsPromises`

```
import { mkdir } from 'node:fs/promises';
mkdir('./carpeta_nueva').then(...);
```